# Pattern в Input - всё, кроме ввода только нулей

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, input, шаблоны-проектирования

Привет народ, прошу помощи!

Нужно в `input`'е задать `pattern`.

`input` не должен допускать ввод только нулей:

> 0; 000

`input` может допускать ввод символов и цифр:

> abc0; 0абв; 123абв; абв0123

Comment: Привет, как дила?

Comment: @maxnemo, так проверьте чтобы был хотя бы один допустимый символ отличный от нуля и все ок.

Comment: pattern    /^[?0](.*?)/  по моему так задается,щас проверю

Comment: Проверить на *несовпадение* шаблону `/^0+$/`

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант решения:

```html
 <form name="test" method="get" action="#">
  <p><b>Ваше имя:</b><br>
   <input type="text" size="40" pattern=".*[1-9A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё].*" placeholder="Минимум 1 буква или цифра от 1 до 9" required>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
 </form>
```

Если же разрешены только русские и латинские буквы и цифры, то такой вариант:

```html
 <form name="test" method="get" action="#">
  <p><b>Ваше имя:</b><br>
   <input type="text" size="40" pattern="(?=.*[1-9A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё])[\dA-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]+" placeholder="Только буквы и цифры" required>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

ещё вот так мне посоветовали, коротко :)

```
pattern="(?!0+$)[\D0-9]+"
```

Comment: Паттерн пропустит `0.00`.

Comment: Вряд ли символ перевода строки возможен в поле input. `[\D0-9]` можно заменить точкой.